# Orfeo Toolbox PCA fails - Null Eigen value?

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, eigen-values

I am using the Orfeo ToolBox to do a PCA on a `.tif` with 3060 timesteps of temperature values.

The PCA runs either in the Ubuntu CMD line or in QGIS.

In both, I get the same error saying:

> Null Eigen value

I already found the lines which are throwing the error in the original Python file but I can't figure out what is exactly going wrong.

Can anyone explain this error to me?

Comment: What do the lines say in the python file?

Comment: This is likely a singular value decomposition problem. Some of your rasters or pixel-vector values may be uniform in value, especially zeros.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question:
The Orfeo ToolBox PCA algorithm doesn't allow raster stacks to have layers where all the pixels are filled with 0. When applying the PCA there will be a division by 0. Therefore I deleted all layers containing only 0 value pixels.